# In Corda Network map - How and where are the end points called?

Tags: corda

In https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#http-network-map-protocol in Corda docs. It is mentioned that, every node on startup will publish its signed node-info to the Server and this is achieved thru the Rest end-point "/network-map/publish". Can someone help me understanding when and which part of the Corda hits it ? And how is that called ? Where should I look into to understand this ?

I saw the Corda code - https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/24fa695ca0ef72fa851abc5b1630d722f32577ec/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/network/NetworkMapClient.kt and it has a publish function. Is this where it is taken care ? If so, how is this function called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the node starts up, it calls `AbstractNode.start()`. Inside `start()`, we see this call:

```
val (keyPairs, nodeInfoAndSigned, myNotaryIdentity) = database.transaction {
    updateNodeInfo(identity, identityKeyPair, publish = true)
}
```

Then inside `AbstractNode.updateNodeInfo()`, we see:

```
if (publish && networkMapClient != null) {
    tryPublishNodeInfoAsync(nodeInfoAndSigned.signed, networkMapClient)
}
```

And finally inside `AbstractNode.tryPublishNodeInfoAsync()`, we see:

```
networkMapClient.publish(signedNodeInfo)
```

This is the method that publishes the node's information to the network map.